# Generalized Laplace equation

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

When considering electric potential $\Phi(\vec{r})$ in the presence of dielectric material described by relative permittivity $\epsilon(\vec{r})$, one has to solve the generalized Laplace equation $$\vec{\nabla} \cdot (\epsilon \vec{\nabla} \Phi) = 0.$$ I am interested in some basic properties of this equation. For example, are Dirichlet and Neumann problems well posed in this case? How many of its properties does this equation inherit from the ordinary Laplace equation?

Comment: There is a vast literature on this subject, which stems from a paper of Littman, Stampacchia and Weinberger from the sixties of the twentieth century: those researches are very technical, dealing for example with the case when the permittivity $\epsilon$ is a symmetric tensor whose coefficients need only to be bounded and measurable (no differentiability nor continuity requirements).